# How do you write the global_rng state to file, so I can load it for later use?

Tags: random, file-io, julia

I have a code that takes a long time to run, longer than the max allowed walltime on the cluster. It relies on rand(), so in order to run the code in multiple sequences on the cluster, I am using

```
julia> r = copy(Random.GLOBAL_RNG)
```

to capture the state of the global random number generator at the end of a run. I need to save 'r' to a file, then read that variable from the file when I start up the next run on the cluster -- in essence to be able to "pick up where I left off". When I try (using the package DelimitedFiles):

```
julia> writedlm("rngState.bin",r)
```

however, I get the following error

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching iterate(::MersenneTwister)
Closest candidates are:
  iterate(::Core.SimpleVector) at essentials.jl:568
  iterate(::Core.SimpleVector, ::Any) at essentials.jl:568
  iterate(::ExponentialBackOff) at error.jl:199
```

Which leads me to believe that the state of a Mersenne Twister rng is not something that can be written to a file. Is this correct? Does anyone know how I could save the state of the GLOBAL_RNG to a file so I can read it back in later to pick up where I left off?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the functionality of the built-in standard library `Serialization`:

```
julia> using Random, Serialization

julia> rng = MersenneTwister(); # create random generator

julia> rand(rng, 3)
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.3708879403326799
 0.46672369641612566
 0.5728925387391

julia> open("out.bin", "w") do f
           serialize(f, rng) # serialize rng to file
       end

julia> rng_loaded = deserialize("out.bin"); # load & deserialize rng from file

julia> rand(rng, 3)
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.6210629081706212
 0.8568331464134413
 0.7247872543135467

julia> rand(rng_loaded, 3) # same numbers
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.6210629081706212
 0.8568331464134413
 0.7247872543135467
```

You can use the same technique to store `Random.GLOBAL_RNG` to file. Setting it isn't as trivial as `Random.GLOBAL_RNG = rng_loaded` though as you're trying to assign a variable in another module (which isn't allowed). You can, however, use `copy!(Random.GLOBAL_RNG, rng_loaded)` to overwrite it in-place.

Note that the serialization format can, in principle, change in future Julia versions. In this case, you wouldn't be able to read old rng files anymore. If you plan to store rngs for a longer period of time, consider storing their individual fields in, say, a HDF5 file. (You can find some inspiration [here](https://github.com/crstnbr/Helpers.jl/blob/master/src/hdf5.jl#L83).)

UPDATE: replaced my stupid `set_global_rng` function with `copy!` as indicated by @Matt B in his answer.

Comment: Hah, you just barely beat me to it!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to write the RNG to a delimited file, but its internals are far more complicated than a simple CSV could support.  Instead, I'd use the Serialization module:

```
julia> using Random, Serialization

julia> open("rng.jls", "w") do f
           serialize(f, Random.GLOBAL_RNG)
       end

julia> rand(1, 5)
1×5 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.747507  0.279039  0.839956  0.265125  0.194283

julia> open("rng.jls") do f
           mt = deserialize(f)
           copy!(Random.GLOBAL_RNG, mt)
       end

julia> rand(1, 5)
1×5 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.747507  0.279039  0.839956  0.265125  0.194283
```